# font awesome same size links

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to create same size button (hyperlink) with FontAwesome.

HTML as below:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-info" href="#">
 Button 1 Info<br /> sub<br />
<i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x pull-right"></i>
</a>


<a class="btn btn-lg btn-info" href="#">
  Button 2<br /><br />
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-2x pull-right"></i>
</a>


<a class="btn btn-lg btn-info" href="#">
  Button<br /><br />
<i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-2x pull-right"></i>
</a>
```

See Image as below.

All button should be of same size
[image]

Is there any inbuilt css class in font awesome?

Comment: Please include your relevant CSS code, too. It will help if we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Fixed Width Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#fixed-width)

Comment: I was using bootstrap and font-awsome from cdn. Added following css class: .button-SameSize
{
 
  width: 9em;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
}  And then added the class <a class="btn btn-lg btn-SameSize btn-info" href="#"> And it worked